# Debugging in multi-project under one solution in vs 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have multiple projects in one solution.  Project A (the starting project) starts Project B using `Process.Start`.

All the debugging methods work fine in project A, however after A starts B, not only do breakpoints not work, but also the output from calls to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` is not displayed.

Does anyone know how to debug in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario you have 2 processes running and you need to attach Visual Studio to both of them.  Visual Studio supports attaching to multiple processes and getting it to do so is the same as attaching to a single process.  Once the second process is launched do the following

- Tools -> Attach to Process
- Select the process
- Hit Attach

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I need to  add some blocking codes in the beginning of project b.

Comment: @Prophet, why not just add a `Debug.Break` call?

Comment: @Jared: You mean `Debugger.Break`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx

Comment: nice !  first time see this awesome function.

Answer (score 1):

The new process which is created at runtime will not have the debugger attached hence breakpoints and debug.writeline won't work.

You might be able to select "Debug" menu then "Attach to process" from within Visual Studio once the new process is running.

Answer (score 1):

You are debugging the process that Project A is working and because you are starting a second process for Project B you have not attached your debugger to that process. So you need to attach to the second process.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an call to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` in the Main from Project B. So every time you start Project B it will ask you if you want to attach a Debugger.